# Problema cambio de target por javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema que no sé como resolver. Adjunto el fragmento de código

```
<li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-61">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/loquesea">
    <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

El problema es que necesito añadir por js el target a una nueva pestaña en ese link debido a que no puedo tocar directamente el código html.

Había creado el siguiente código:

```
function cambiatarget() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].target = "_blank";
  }
}
cambiatarget();
```

Pero el problema como es lógico es que me varía todos los `a` de la página. cómo podría acceder únicamente a ese link?

Comment: Pues, sacándole provecho al id del elemento `<li></li>` ;-)

Comment: La idea la tenía pero el problema es que no sé como expresarla! Cómo se nota que estoy comenzando;)
No sé como capturar el id y el "a" interior de éste  a la vez para modificar el target

Comment: Claro, entiendo. Solo te estaba dando una pista :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en la instrucción `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` estas obteniendo la referencia todos los elementos `a` de tu html. Lo que debes hacer para resolver el problema, es hacer referencia solamente al elemento que necesitas.

```js
function cambiatarget() {
    var link = document.querySelector("#menu-item-61 a");
    link.target = "_blank";
}
cambiatarget();
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-61">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/loquesea">
        <i class="icon-twitter">TWIIER</i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Genial!!! Me apunto lo del querySelector que no lo había visto todavía. Muchas gracias a los dos!